# Bootstrap + Magento UI with LESS and Materialize

Tags: magento2

What is the best way to integrate a CSS/JS library with Magento 2?

I understand that Magento is packaged with it's own UI library however it does not contain half of the features in modern frameworks. (bootstrap/materialize/etc).

With a theme extended from blank, including bootstrap causes conflict due to class names being the same (.modal-content or .mark for example).

With a theme that has no parent, Require JS doesn't work and it will take a long time to go through and re-write everything.

So, how can we use an external library without conflict?

How are you integrating JS/CSS frameworks?